# Is there a way to generate an "infinite" amount of charts using chart.js in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I am relatively new to Django and HTML.

I need to display many charts on one page in Django. I know that I need to give each of these charts a different id value in the  tag, but haven't been able to. Here's what I'm working with.

```
<script>var count = 0;</script>
<ul>
  {% for object in objects %}
    <li>
    <script>
        {% block jquery %}
        count = count + 1;
...
        eval('var chart_id = "myChart' + count + '"');
        eval('var ctx' + count + ' = document.getElementById(chart_id)');
        eval('var myChart =  new Chart(ctx' + count + ', graph_data)');`
{% endblock jquery %}           
</script>
<canvas id= myChart1 width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't been able to pass in variables to the id of the  tag or find an equivalent to the eval() function that could work in HTML.

The real maximum number of charts I could need is roughly 100, but I am trying to treat it as if it's an infinite number. Worst case, I could use brute force and make 100 if statements that say if the count is a certain number, display the corresponding chart, but I am trying to find a cleaner solution.

If there isn't a way to do this and anyone knows of a chart system better for my specific needs than chart.js, please let me know. I tried matplotlib, but the graph I need is a double line graph (which matplotlib doesn't like).

Comment: Where is your data coming from/what are you going to loop over to generate your charts?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have a class that I created in my models.py that has data associated with it that I am going to pass into graph_data for each graph

Comment: @IainShelvington it also is good to note I'm using jquery so I've edited the post